# Nonlinear Equality and Inequality Constraints in matlab optimization toolbox

Tags: matlab, optimization, minimization

I need to optimize following function:
f(x) = x^2 + y^3 + z^4

with constraints:
x + y + z = 10
1.5 + x*y - z <= 0

x*y >= -10

and limitations:
-10 <= x <= 10
-5 <= y <= 5
0 <= z <= inf

I need to use those options:
'LargeScale' = 'off', 'GradObj' =' on', 'GradConstr' = 'on',
and my code looks like:

```
options = optimset('LargeScale', 'off', 'GradObj','on','GradConstr','on');
A = [-1 0 0
  1 0 0
  0 -1 0
  0 1 0
  0 0 -1];
b = [-10 10 -5 5 0];
Aeq = [1 1 1];
beq = [10];
[x fval] = fmincon(@fun,[0 0 0],A, b, Aeq, beq,[],[],@constr, options);

function [y,g] = fun(x)
y = x(1).^2+x(2).^3+x(3).^4;
    if nargout > 1
        g = [2*x(1), 3*x(2).^2, 4*x(3).^3];
    end
end
function [c,ceq, GC, GCeq] = constr(x)
    c(1) = 1.5 + x(1)*x(2) - x(3);
    c(2) = -10 - x(1)*x(2);
    ceq = [];
    if nargout > 2
        GC = [x(2), -x(2);
              x(1), -x(1);
              0   ,    0];
        GCeq = [];
    end
end
```

Expected results are:
x = 10
y = -1
z = 0.05

Can you give me an advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linear constraints you are applying to `x(1)` and `x(2)` are incorrect. The two constraints acting on `x(1)`, as you have given them, would be expressed as:

```
x(1) <= 10
-x(1) <= -10
```

The only value that satisfies these is `x(1)=10`. Set both RHS values to 10 and you will enforce the bounds on `x(1)` that you are trying to achieve.

Also, the gradient that you provide for your first non-linear constraint is incorrect, you are missing the -1 value for the gradient with respect to `x(3)`.

I've made the modifications below. When I run this I get an optimal solution of `[8.3084    0.0206    1.6710]`. I don't believe the expected results you provided are correct, they do not satisfy the equality constraint of `x + y + z = 10`

```
options = optimset('LargeScale', 'off', 'GradObj','on','GradConstr','on');
A = [-1 0 0
  1 0 0
  0 -1 0
  0 1 0
  0 0 -1];
b = [10 10 5 5 0];
Aeq = [1 1 1];
beq = [10];
[x fval] = fmincon(@fun,[0 0 0],A, b, Aeq, beq,[],[],@constr, options);

function [y,g] = fun(x)
y = x(1).^2+x(2).^3+x(3).^4;
    if nargout > 1
        g = [2*x(1), 3*x(2).^2, 4*x(3).^3];
    end
end
function [c,ceq, GC, GCeq] = constr(x)
c(1) = 1.5 + x(1)*x(2) - x(3);
c(2) = -10 - x(1)*x(2);
ceq = [];
if nargout > 2
    GC = [x(2), -x(2);
          x(1), -x(1);
          -1   ,    0];
    GCeq = [];
end
```